# Program does not exit. How to find out what python is doing?

Tags: python

I have a python script which is working fine so far. However, my program does not exit properly. I can debug until and I'm returning to the end, but the programm keeps running.

main.main() does a lot of stuff: it downloads (http, ftp, sftp, ...) some csv files from a data provider, converts the data into a standardized file format and loads everyting into the database.

This works fine. However, the program does not exit. How can I find out, where the programm is "waiting"?
There exist more than one provider - the script terminates correctly for all providers except for one (sftp download, I'm using paramiko)

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    main.log = main.log2both
    filestoconvert = []
    #filestoconvert = glob.glob(r'C:\Data\Feed\ProviderName\download\*.csv')
    main.main(['ProviderName'], ['download', 'convert', 'load'], filestoconvert)
```

I'm happy for any thoughts and ideas!

Comment: You can simply add a signal, which will exit the script after some time. If it can not reach the provider in, for example, two minutes, it will run `sys.exit(1)` and log it somewhere, but will not hang up like now. If you would like me to write an example on this, I can give a full answer.

Comment: Well, it sounds reasonable, thank you. But I still want to know what is going on. A timed sys.exit would be a "workaround" if I don't find out what's causing this behavior.

Answer (score 15):

If your program does not terminate it most likely means you have a thread still working.

To list all the running threads you can use :

```
threading.enumerate()
```

This function lists all Thread that are currently running (see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate))

If this is not enough you might need a bit of script along with the function (see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys._current_frames)):

```
sys._current_frames()
```

So to print stacktrace of all alive threads you would do something like :

```
import sys, traceback, threading
thread_names = {t.ident: t.name for t in threading.enumerate()}
for thread_id, frame in sys._current_frames().iteritems():
    print("Thread %s:" % thread_names.get(thread_id, thread_id))
    traceback.print_stack(frame)
    print()
```

Good luck !

Comment: I tried this, but there's only the main thread, and still Python wouldn't exit. How else would you debug this?

Answer (score 3):

This question is 10 years old, but I post my solution for someone with a similar issue with a non-finishing Python script like mine.

In my case, the debugging process didn't help. All debugging outputs showed only one thread. But the suggestion by @JC Plessis that some work should be going on helped me find the cause.

I was using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/) with the chrome driver, and I was finishing the selenium process after closing the only tab that was open with

```python
driver.close()
```

But later, I changed the code to use a headless browser, and the Selenium driver wasn't closed after `driver.close()`, and the python script was stuck indefinitely. It results that the right way to shutdown the Selenium driver was actually.

```python
driver.quit()
```

That solved the problem, and the script was finally finishing again.

Comment: Not sure how the stars aligned and I stumbled upon this. I was running a batch script with exit near the end and it would show that the exit went through but didn't execute.

Comment: @AndrewValdez same! +1

Answer (score 2):

You can involve the python debugger for a script.py with

```
python -m pdb script.py
```

You find the pdb commands at http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

Comment: I think I did this already. The point is I reach the end of main.main(...) and afterwards nothing happens...

Comment: did you step into this function ? "s" is the command. if you press "n" for "next" you step over this call.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use [GDB](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb), which allows to pinpoint hung processes, like jstack in Java

Comment: This won't be very useful for Python, you'll end up mired in implementation detail of the Python interpreter.

Comment: This actually works well with gdb python extensions. Try "py-bt" for backtraces or "thread apply all py-bt". Also see https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sys.settrace`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) to pinpoint which function blocks. Then you can use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) to step through it.